# Java, Eclipse, Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project: simple telegram bot. It worked while I didn't tried deploy it on Heroku. I did a backup for stable version, but Eclipse keeps showing me this ERROR. IDK what's wrong with it, I tried a lot of stuff, like what's the problem? I have src folder, classes also, I have main... Maybe problem in .gitignore file?
But I deleted from it *.class, it's still not working. Help
It's not a duplicate, because I'm workin in Eclipse and it worked earlier. Added my folder properties.  I need short answer, not just a wiki of possible problems because it doesnt help.
[Folder props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaDdP.png)

[Screenshot error and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOFWg.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors. It's hard for search engines to index, hard for some people to read, etc etc

Comment: @Michael Its not just a screenshot of Error, it shows my folders

Answer (score 0):

Your project configuration is very bizarre; you have class files in a directory named 'SRC'. It's hard to tell what you did to manage to create a project def this bizarre. Some ideas:

- You've compiled this on the command line. You should probably look into build systems like maven or gradle to build your code. Even if not, use the -d switch on javac to ensure the class files end up in a directory named 'bin' or 'build'.
- You've turned off eclipse's autocompile function. Turn it back on.
- Right click your Point.java file (not Point.class) and pick 'run...' from the context menu. Assuming autocompile is on this will work.
- Generally, use packages. Stuff in the default package is unrunnable in various scenarios. From what I can tell you're not in one of those 'default package is not runnable' scenarios but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Build automatically is on, I also haved bin folder, but it didnt work so I added classes and java files in one folder but it doesnt work